# Объединить 2 JSON из разных процессоров NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

На схеме указал основные шаги
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По сути мы сначала из одного источника получаем массив JSON объектов в которых есть некоторые данные
Потом получаем id этих данных
Потом получаем доп.инфу по этому id
далее нам надо как-то объединить эти данные, поместив данные из второго запроса,например, в items

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение.
Для начала нам надо знать сколько JSON объектов мы объединяем.

Теперь нам надо создать группу и указать что она конкурентная `Process Group FlowFile Concurrency=Single FlowFile Per Node`.

Далее в группе делаем следующую структуру в группе
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройка InvokeHTTP думаю описывать не надо.

Далее в MergeContent настраиваем:

- Merge Strategy=Bin-Packing Algorithm
- Merge Format=Binary Concatenation
- Attribute Strategy=Keep Only Common Attributes
- Minimum Number of Entries=2
- Maximum Number of Entries=2
- Delimiter Strategy=Text
- Header=[
- Footer=]
- Demarcator=,

Обратите внимание на значения 2, именно столько у нас запросов.

В результате будет что-то типа

```
[/*JSONFromQuery1*/,/*JSONFromQuery2*/]
```

Отлично. Теперь нам надо их объединить, что делает JOLTTransformJSON.

Его настройки:

Jolt Transformation DSL=Shift

Specification=

```
{
  "*": {
    "*": "&"
  }
}
```

Он объединит наши 2 JSON в 1.

Осталось повесить связи обработки ошибок и готово.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы объединить 2 конкретных (а не любых) JOSN надо использовать стратегию Defragment в процессоре Merge. Для этого рекомендую добавить пару процессоров (в каждую ветку после развилки) UpdateAttribute и задать 3 аттрибута:

```
fragment.identifier = ${filename}
fragment.index = 0 для первой ветки и 1 для второй
fragment.count = 2 (общее колличество фрагментов)
```